# Where to start examining error message when compiling C++ programs?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Often times when compiling a C++ program I face error messages, some are simple to decipher but others are quite challenging since they very long. Typically in Python one would start by looking the last statement in the error message. How should one go about when examining long compiler error messages in C++?

Comment: It depends on the form of the error message, and that depends on which compiler you're using.

Comment: From first. Including warnings

Comment: Assuming compilation time is not really a factor, fix the first error and then recompile.  This helps as often times further errors come up because of the first error.

Comment: If this is Visual Studio I switch to the Output window so that I can get the errors in order. The first error is the one you want to start with. Since in c++ subsequent errors may be caused from the first error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that errors from misuse of templates, probably from the Standard Library, are bugging you. There are several approaches to this, but, I found it best to find the part of the (long) error report that is related to *my* code, and not some STL header (say, `<vector>`). Then you can try to deduce the error from there, going back-and forth to other errors reported, "following the types".

There are also some "error parsers" out there, they are dependent on your compiler and its version, but, some people have found them useful. "STLFilt" is one, but I never used it, so can't say how good is it.

Also, try to compile with `CLang`, it has better error reporting than most compilers, though GCC has been catching up lately. It has "drop-in" replacements for GCC and CL (Microsoft Visual C/C++ compiler).

Answer (score 1):

Start with the first error(s). Those are usually the most relevant. Later errors are often caused by the first ones, so eliminating the first errors usually also elliminates a bunch of the following ones. Rinse-repeat until all are fixed.

As mentioned in another answer, compiling your code with multiple different compilers can often be helpful since they will present the errors in different ways and some errors produce better (more understandable) error reports with some compilers than others. Having the problem described in different ways can often help understanding (I personally build everything with clang 3.8, gcc 6.1 and VS2015 and besides helping with different error output, different compilers also catch different bugs - added bonus).